# Hash function required for custom data structure containing 12 integers

Tags: c++11, hash, hashcode, unordered-set, custom-data-type

I have a custom structure that holds 12 integer values, x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4,x5,y5,x6,y6.

The range of the numbers is between 1 and 5 inclusive and every structure is guaranteed to have different combinations i.e **NO** two structures can have all the values of x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4,x5,y5,x6,y6 same as the respective values of other.

I need a good hash function to perform O(1) operations.

The requirement is to find out a structure with specific x1,y1....x6,y6 values

Right now I am using the following:-

```
struct Hash_6
{
size_t operator () ( const Node& n ) const
{

        int result=17;
        result=31*result+n.x1;
        result=31*result+n.x2;
        result=31*result+n.x3;
        result=31*result+n.x4;
        result=31*result+n.x5;
        result=31*result+n.x6;
        result=31*result+n.y1;
        result=31*result+n.y2;
        result=31*result+n.y3;
        result=31*result+n.y4;
        result=31*result+n.y5;
        result=31*result+n.y6;
        return result;
}
};
```

I want to know if there is any better more efficient hash function out there which I could use for this specific case.

Comment: If the values are between 1-5 why don't use you 5*result instead of 31? 5^12 fits comfortably inside a 32 bit int and will give you unique hash values per combination so that after you modulo your hash-bucket width, a simple hash comparison will tell you if you have an exact match.

Comment: Well actually my knowledge about making hash functions is below average, so this is the hash function I am using for most of my programs

Comment: I will definitely try using 5 and get back. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the values are always between one and five inclusive, then you can get a unique hash within a 32-bit value.

That's because five (the values) to the power of twelve (the number of variables) is `244,140,625`, a value that can be represented in 28 bits.

Hence you hash function becomes (pseudo-code):

```py
def hasher(s):
    res = s.x1 - 1
    for val in s.x2, s.x3, s.x4, s.x5, s.x6 s.y1, s.y2, s.y3, s.y4, s.y5, s.y6:
        res = res * 5 + val - 1;
    return res
```

With your constraints, you get a unique value out of that hash function.

---

If you wanted to use that hash for bucket selection (such as used in a set or dictionary), you would probably want to reduce it with a modulus to a more suitable value (introducing collisions as part of the process).

But it's unclear whether you're needing a hash for identification (leave as is) or bucketing (reduce it). If the latter, and values are reasonably evenly distributed, that would be along the lines of:

```py
bucket_to_use = hasher(item) modulo num_buckets
```